# Having a strange issue with jQuery Cycle Plugin Pager and IE7 and 8

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I'm building a site using the Cycle plugin and using thumbnail images as the pagers. It works great in Firefox, Chrome, and IE9. In IE8 and 7 though I have a really strange issue.

The first image of the pager and the slideshow loads fine. When I click on the second thumbnail to load the second image, the slideshow goes to white (appears as if it's not loading an image or trying to load an image it can't find not entirely sure), when I click the third thumbnail it loads the second image in the slideshow. This pattern of not loading an image and then loading the wrong image continues through the entire slideshow.

Here's the actual jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gallery').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        speed: 500,
        timeout: 0,
        pager: '#slide_navigation',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
            return '#slide_navigation li:eq(' + idx + ') a';
        }
    });
    $("#left").click(function() {
        $("#slide_navigation").animate({"marginLeft": "+=960px"}, "slow");
        $("#left").hide();
        $("#right").show();
    });
    $("#right").click(function() {
        $("#slide_navigation").animate({"marginLeft": "-=960px"}, "slow");
        $("#right").hide();
        $("#left").show();
    });
```

Here's the CSS for the page:

```
#slide_navigation {
    width: 2000px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border:  1px #909090;
    border-style: solid none;
}
#slide_navigation li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 52px 3px 0px 3px;
}
#slide_navigation li:first-child {
    margin-left: 25px;
}
#slide_navigation li.activeSlide {
    background: #F68009;
}
#left {
    width: 20px;
    height: 75px;
    float: left;
    background: #FFFFFF url(prev1.png) no-repeat center;
    position: relative;
    top: -85px;
    left: -3px;
    margin-bottom: -85px;
    display: none;
}
#right {
    width: 20px;
    height: 75px;
    float: right;
    background: #FFFFFF url(next1.png) no-repeat center;
    position: relative;
    top: -85px;
    right: -3px;
    margin-bottom: -85px;
}
```

And just in case - He's the HTML for the pager:

```
<div id="slide_navigation">
    <li><a href="#"><img src=support-1.jpg></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=support-2.jpg></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=support-3.jpg></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=support-4.jpg></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=support-5.jpg></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=support-6.jpg></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=support-7.jpg></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=support-8.jpg></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=support-9.jpg></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=support-10.jpg></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=support-11.jpg></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=support-12.jpg></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=support-13.jpg></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=support-14.jpg></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=support-15.jpg></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=support-16.jpg></a></li>
</div>
<div id="left" class="cursorPointer"></div>
<div id="right" class="cursorPointer"></div>
```

The left and right id's are used to help navigate the slider. Don't think it's related but providing as much info as I can. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you setup a working example on http://jsbin.com for us?

Comment: Never done something at jsbin before but I think I've got it working. http://jsbin.com/ukizac/

Comment: It's a great tool for getting even quicker answers. I've provided a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some mis-matched tag endings. Note the closing `</a>` has no corresponding `<a>` opening tag. Provide the opening tag and it appears to work just fine.

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img src=http://www.howie23.org/rp-help/1.jpg></a>
    <img src=http://www.howie23.org/rp-help/2.jpg></a>
    <img src=http://www.howie23.org/rp-help/3.jpg></a>
    <img src=http://www.howie23.org/rp-help/4.jpg></a>
    <img src=http://www.howie23.org/rp-help/5.jpg></a>
    <img src=http://www.howie23.org/rp-help/6.jpg></a>
    <img src=http://www.howie23.org/rp-help/7.jpg></a>
    <img src=http://www.howie23.org/rp-help/8.jpg></a>
</div>
```

Patched Demo: http://jsbin.com/ukizac/3/edit#preview

Comment: That was it! Can't believe I missed that. Thanks for pointing out the obvious to me. Much appreciated :D